# matlab - "Out Of Memory during serialization of the Subsystem Data" error message

Tags: matlab

This happens when saving a large (300 MB) structure. (It's a `containers.Map` with strings as keys and various large matrices as values.)

Error message:

```
Out Of Memory during serialization of the Subsystem Data
Error using save
Error closing file C:\a\comsol\fibre_bundle_AP.mat.

Error in process_data3/saveData (line 132)
        save(save_file, 'data');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/answers/37479), the `save` function in current versions of Matlab makes a copy of the structure that it is saving. This may cause Matlab to run out of memory.

One solution is to use an older version of `save`, as follows:

```
save(save_file, 'data', '-v7.3');
```

The above solves the problem for me.

Comment: Have you heard of any issues regarding compatibility?

Comment: Indeed. Some weeks after this question, I wanted to open the file in Octave, and that didn't work. So I tried the normal `save(save_file, 'data')` in Matlab and that worked slightly better, but still didn't work in Octave, because I had a `containers.Map` inside it, which I use a lot since it gives namespaces.  Anyway, had to flatten the namespaces, and avoid using `-v7.3` (if I remember correctly).